# ASP Classic My company has a homegrown app that has issues since a move to Server 2008

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

We have an intranet app that basically queries a bunch of databases and arranges the data. It is written in ASP(I KNOW) and upon a move to Windows Server 2008 we have one field that no longer populates. I know the database connection is good as everything else on that page loads just fine. This leads me to believe that it is a problem with the syntax of that particular query and that since it is using TO_DATE maybe there is some difference between Server 2003 and 2008 in regards to date format.

```
'SQL TO PULL PROCESS GROUP
pgsql = "SELECT DISTINCT subsystem_process_group.subsystem_id, subsystem_process_group.process_group_id, "
pgsql = pgsql & "process_group.process_group_name, oncall_group_day.employee_nbr "
pgsql = pgsql & " FROM eco_admin.process_group, eco_admin.subsystem_process_group, eco_admin.oncall_group_day "
pgsql = pgsql & "WHERE ((process_group.process_group_id = subsystem_process_group.process_group_id) "
pgsql = pgsql & "AND (process_group.process_group_id = oncall_group_day.process_group_id(+)) "
pgsql = pgsql & "AND (ONCALL_GROUP_DAY.CALENDAR_DATE(+) = TO_DATE(SYSDATE)) "
pgsql = pgsql & "AND (oncall_group_day.oncall_member_role_code(+) = 'P" & hour(now) & "') "
pgsql = pgsql & "AND (subsystem_process_group.subsystem_id = " & request("id") & ")) " 

function get_name(emp_nbr)
    sql3 = "select LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(COMMON_NAME))) COMMON_NAME, LTRIM(RTRIM(INITCAP(LAST_NAME))) last_name from (select EMPLOYEE_NBR,COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from hrit_admin.employee union all  select   CONTRACT_RESOURCE_ID, COMMON_NAME, LAST_NAME  from   hrit_admin.contract_resource) a where employee_nbr = a.employee_nbr and employee_nbr = " & emp_nbr
    rs3.open sql3,conn
    get_name = rs3("COMMON_NAME") & " " & rs3("LAST_NAME")
    rs3.close
end function
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the code that's using `TO_DATE`?

Comment: Code added, thank you for looking.

Comment: Ouch - I'd forgotten how nasty old ASP code (and old Oracle code) can be. Whatever you're getting paid, it's not enough :)  The `TO_DATE(SYSDATE)` is harmless enough, though it is redundant because `SYSDATE` is a date to begin with. Bottom line, I'm not sure the `TO_DATE(SYSDATE)` is the problem. I know it's a pain, but I'd recommend supplying values for `hour(now)` and `request("id")` and running the query from SQLPlus. That may help point you in the right direction.

Comment: all sorts of weird errors trying to get the query running against the database.  I uploaded the full page code if that would help any.  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:34b8  Thanks.